# Build Jenkins job using GitLab webhook

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I am looking for a secure way to build a parameterized `Jenkins` job with an API Token using `GitLab` webhooks, preferably using a GitLab API token. I have found a way to do this using a POST request, as seen [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API), but GitLab does not let me send custom POST requests as webhooks.

All of the options I have found online involve disabling some of the security features in Jenkins to get around 403 Invalid Crumb errors which I do not want to do.

I looked into using the GitLab Plugin detailed here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin but as far as I can tell you can't pass parameters in builds using this plugin outside of the params that are passed by default in the Webhook POST request, and we need to be able to pass custom parameters in our builds.

Comment: How about [defined variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables) of gitlab plugin? Maybe the parameters you want to pass are already there?

Comment: @makozaki Unfortunately I am looking to pass in some custom variables that relate to internal business logic

Comment: Why don't you do it directly on jenkins? E.g. as default variables or as part of the jenkins job logic?

Comment: @makozaki That would work for all but one of the options - one is the git branch of the service to deploy. We can't use a default value for that as the git plugin that actually pulls the code inside Jenkins doesn't support a default value - it points at the parameter where the branch is chosen, which does have a default value option, but it doesn't recognize it on build if it isn't chosen manually